# Best Way to Auto Generate Id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to generate Id or Code column(primary key) in a table in SQL Server? My requirement is a big table which stores more than 1000000 rows.

So generally we create auto identity column of a table but is it the best way? For example, I have an employee_master table and there are three columns like

```
emp_id  auto increment
Emp_code  varchar(20)
and also default like Rowno of a table.
```

So in this scenario, it has 3 unique columns of a table. Is it the best way?
Or what is the best way to generate id/code column both master and transaction table.

Also is there any way which we generate financial year wise auto-generate column.(any function)

Comment: ID would be more preferred than Key but having key in addition to that will be much more helpful when you have like Type II dimension table and related fact tables.

Comment: pls explain with an example if any

Comment: Thats not really a question - what alternatives to an `identity` column are you considering?

Comment: yes..what is the best way?for example Emp_id,Emp_code.so emp_id is identity and emp_code is manual auto increment.is the best way to store both or one.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking. You know what your requirements are and whether you need multiple columns or not. No one else can advise on that.

Comment: i have column like SALARY_CODE-SAL/01-1819 FN_YEAR=18-19. i need value increement like SAL/02-18-19,SAL/03-18-19.but if FN_YEAR=19-20 then it should be SAL/01-1920,SAL/02-19-20....

Answer (score -1):

The following SQL statement defines the "ID" column to be an auto-increment primary key field in the "Persons" table

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

I think this will work..

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: i have value like SALARY_CODE-SAL/01-1819      FN_YEAR=18-19. i need value increement like SAL/02-1819,SAL/03-1819.but if FN_YEAR=19-20 then it should be SAL/01-1920.